# String manipulation in Java

Tags: java, strings

Here is the question followed by my working program:

> Given a string, return a version without the first 2 chars. Except
>   keep the first char if it is 'a' and keep the second char if it is
>   'b'. The string may be any length. Harder than it looks.
>
> ```
> deFront("Hello") → "llo"  
> deFront("java") → "va"  
> deFront("away") → "aay"
> ```

Can this code be improved?

```
public String deFront(String str) {
    if (str.length() >= 2) {
        char firstCharacter = str.charAt(0);
        char secondCharacter = str.charAt(1);
        if (firstCharacter == 'a' && secondCharacter == 'b') {
            // donot skip
            return str;
        } else if (firstCharacter == 'a' && secondCharacter != 'b') {
            // skip first character only
            return str.substring(0, 1) + str.substring(2);
        } else if (firstCharacter != 'a' && secondCharacter == 'b') {
            // skip second character only
            return str.substring(1);
        } else {
            return str.substring(2);
        }
    } else if (str.length() == 1 && str.charAt(0) == 'a') {
        return str;
    } else {
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Fix the indentation so it's easier to read.

Comment: Also please fix the title and replace it with something meaningful.

Comment: You should write some unit tests to check your function.

Answer (score 10):

Just recoded it, doing simply what your explanation said

> Except keep the first char if it is 'a' and keep the second char if
>   it is 'b'.

Since a possible deletion of a character will affect indices, we check the second character before we check the first.
The resulting code is much simpler and readable simply because the extracted method `deleteCharIfNotEqualTo()` does away with some code duplication and at the same time heightens readability of the `deFront()` method, by explaining what is happening.

```
public String deFront(String str) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(str);
    deleteCharIfNotEqualTo(builder, 1, 'b');
    deleteCharIfNotEqualTo(builder, 0, 'a');
    return builder.toString();
}

private void deleteCharIfNotEqualTo(StringBuilder builder, int index, char character) {
    if (builder.length() > index && character != builder.charAt(index)) {
        builder.deleteCharAt(index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
public static String deFront(String str)
{
    String one = (str.length() > 0 && str.charAt(0) == 'a') ? "a" : "";
    String two = (str.length() > 1 && str.charAt(1) == 'b') ? "b" : "";

    return one+two+((str.length() > 2) ? str.substring(2) : "");        
}
```

Note that only the parentheses around the entire ternary operation in the return are actually necessary, the others are for readability, as per @abuzittingillifirca's suggestion.

Comment: This throws a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` for strings of length 0 and 1.

Comment: True. I only tested strings of length 2. Fixed my code above. Sorry for all the ternary crap, but I find a bunch of ifs would needlessly clutter this simple function.

Comment: Why create substrings for single character equality tests, rather than, e.g, `str.charAt(0)=='a'`?

Comment: +1 for closely matching the description, conciseness and robustness (w.r.t. @bowmore's order dependent deletion).
In addition to @SoftwareMonkey's `charAt` critique:
Ternary operators are OK, But use parentheses and spaces around operators to improve readability of expressions. Also you should declare variables where they are assigned, this is not C or javascript. Use English names whenever international readers may *possibly* see the code (that is always on codereview).

Comment: Thanks! Edited. I had actually used chars and `charAt` first, but since you can't have empty chars, I switched. You're right, chars do fine for the comparison.

Comment: +1 I like this better now. My solutions also had order dependent deletion, which I didn't really like. Nice work!

Answer (score 4):

First, is this part correct?

```
} else if (str.length() == 1 && str.charAt(0) == 'a') {
    return str;
} else {
    return str;
}
```

This will return a string of length 1, unchanged, regardless of the character. What should happen if you pass "z"? Since the first character is not 'a', should it be removed?

I suspect it was supposed to be something like this:

```
} else if (str.length() == 1 && str.charAt(0) != 'a') {
    return "";
} else {
    return str;
}
```

The rest of this answer assumes it should remove the character

You could use a `StringBuilder` and delete the characters as necessary:

```
public String deFront(String str) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    if (sb.length() > 1 && sb.charAt(1) != 'b') {
        sb.deleteCharAt(1);
    }
    if (sb.length() > 0 && sb.charAt(0) != 'a') {
        sb.deleteCharAt(0);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Or you could use a regular expression search & replace:

```
public String deFront(String str) {
    str = str.replaceFirst("^(.)[^b]", "$1");
    str = str.replaceFirst("^[^a]", "");
    return str;
}
```

Note: The order of deletion is important in both of these solutions. The `b` is deleted first to prevent the deletion of `a` from shifting the `b` by one position.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a number of interesting things with this problem. I chose to have a little fun with the fact that A and B are basically self-indicators of which position in the string they may stay in. It also allows you to expand the progressive character search throughout any length of string with just a one-line change. Forgive if my syntax isn't correct, my native language is C#.

```
public String deFront(String str) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int a = (int)'a';

    for(int i = 0; i < 2 && i < str.length()) {
        char cur = str.charAt(i);
        if (i < 2 && (int)cur - a != i) {
            continue;
        }
        sb.append(cur);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

And to apply this to the entire alphabet (repeating after the 26th character):

```
public String deFront(String str) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int a = (int)'a';

    for(int i = 0; i < 2 && i < str.length()) {
        char cur = str.charAt(i);
        if ((int)cur - a != i % 26) { // changed this line here
            continue;
        }
        sb.append(cur);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this algorithm can be at least improved by adding option to check for any list characters at position 0 and 1.

---

```
public class DeFront {

    //if character is one of these, it will be removed
    private static char[] firstLetterExcluded = "a".toCharArray();
    private static char[] secondLetterExcluded = "bcdef".toCharArray();

    public static String deFront(String str) {
        boolean removeFirst = false, removeSecond = false;

        for (char c : firstLetterExcluded) {
            if (str.charAt(0) == c) {
                removeFirst = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        for (char c : secondLetterExcluded) {
            if (str.charAt(1) == c) {
                removeSecond = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        //Before calling the stripping method, it's better to check if we need to
        if (removeFirst || removeSecond) {
            return stripString(str, removeFirst, removeSecond);
        } else {
            return str;
        }
    }

    private static String stripString(String str, boolean removeFirst, boolean removeSecond) {

        if (removeFirst && removeSecond) {
            return str.substring(2);
        } else if (removeFirst) {
            return str.substring(1);
        } else {
            //Using Stringbuilder takes more time
            return str.charAt(0) + str.substring(2);
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily efficient, but compact:

```
public static String deFront(String s)
{
  return Pattern.compile("(?:(a)|[^a])(?:(?:(b)|[^b])(.*))?").matcher(s).replaceFirst("$1$2$3");
}
```

Note that there is a significant performance penalty with this solution, so don't use it if you call the function frequently. This is just to show an alternative using a regular expression.

Comment: why would you do this instead of what the original post does?  please put that into your answer.   thank you